# I have connected expressjs, nodejs, reactjs, and mysql. Why does my code work fine when I restart my express server but break when I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, debugging

users.js in express folder

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const connection = require('./MySQL.js')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  connection.connect()

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users;", (err, rows) => {
    if(err) {
      res.status(404).send(err)
    } else {
      // console.log(rows)
      const result = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
      console.log(result)
      // result.forEach((v) => console.log(v));
      res.send(rows)
    }
  })

  connection.end()
});

module.exports = router;
```

Login.js in react folder

```js
import React from 'react'
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Login.css'

import { Header } from './Header'

export class Login extends React.Component {

    // constructor(props) {
    //     super(props)
    //     this.state = { users: [] }
    // }

    // componentDidMount() {
    //     fetch('/users')
    //         .then(res => res.json())
    //         .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
    // }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <h2 id="login_h2">Log In</h2>
                <div className="login">    
                    <form id="login" method="get">    
                        <label>Username</label>    
                        <input type="text" name="Uname" className="login_info" placeholder="Username"/>    
                        <br/><br/><br/>

                        <label>Password</label>    
                        <input type="Password" name="Pass" className="login_info" placeholder="Password" />    
                        <br/><br/><br/>

                        <input type="button" name="log" id="log" value="Submit" />       
                        <br/><br/>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />    
                        <span>Remember me</span>    

                        <a href="www.codecademy.com">Forgot Password?</a>    
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ShowUsers/>
            </div>
    
        )
    }
}


class ShowUsers extends React.Component {
  state = {users: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**If I Ctrl^C my express server in the terminal and restart it, my code works fine and displays what it should. However, if I refresh the website, everything works fine except what is supposed to be received from the express route.**
I get these error messages in the console:

```js
Login.js:56 GET http://localhost:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
componentDidMount @ Login.js:56
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20663
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:7
./src/index.js @ index.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ reportWebVitals.js:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1


VM628:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
```

And my express server crashes and in the terminal this error message is displayed:

```js
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:215:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\routes\users.js:40:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:232:10)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:12)
    at C:\Users\poppe\Documents\VSCode\Projects\vsc_projects\Track Our Choices 2\react-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:236:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT',
  fatal: false
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems like you are opening and closing the connection for every `GET` request. `connection.connect()` and `connection.end()` needs to be present in your `index.js` file.

Comment: I tried that - I tried it in index.js and app.js. Didn't work unfortunately. Maybe be more specific? But I'm not sure because I tried to replace those lines in several ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection.connect()` accepts a callback function and in that callback function you need to execute the database query, so the code will look like following

```
    connection.connect(function (error) {
    if (error){
        return res.status(404).send(error)
    } ;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users;", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).send(err)
        } else {
            const result = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)));
            console.log(result)
            // result.forEach((v) => console.log(v));
            return res.send(rows)
        }
    })
})
```